# How to fix an image position relative to another image with different screen sizes

Tags: css, positioning

I'm writing a website/iPad app (using [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)), where I have 1024x768 images on a slide show. I'd like to position another image, e.g. the home icon, on top of the 1024x768 images, at exactly the same position, no matter the screen size (e.g. high/low resolution PC screen, or 1024x768 tablet display). I tried absolute, but the position changes in different displays, and it's not the same position as I originally set up in CS 5.

Comment: are you using px to position it?

Comment: yes: #bx-home {
 position:absolute;
 top:700px;
 right:980px;
 z-index:999;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 text-indent: -999999px;
 background: url(home.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to the other answers, but if you prefer not to define the width and height, you can use `float`:

http://jsfiddle.net/RprTY/

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300">    
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/30/30" id="smallone">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

img{
     vertical-align: bottom;   
}

#smallone{
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;   
}
```

As long as the parent container is set to either `position: relative` or `position: absolute`, then the absolutely positioned image should be positioned relative to the top left corner of the parent.  This should be completely independent of screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Put your 1024x768 image in a div of the same size. Include your home icon in that div as well.  Give the div position relative, and the home icon position absolute and it will be absolutely positioned inside it's parent div.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution proposed here but it didn't work. I have basically the same problem: two images inside a slider, one of them is absolute positioned with percentage values (so when I change the width of the viewport it scrolls sideways). The other image should move along with the first one statically positioned in relation to the latter.

The thing is in my case the images are not children of the same parent div. I have set up a Fiddle example of the code I am currently working with.

http://jsfiddle.net/36QPG/1/

```
<div class="image">
    <img id="back" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <div class="image">
        <img id="front" src="http://www.lionsclublagardiecastelnau.com/data/images/images-sites/images/icone-android.png"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's worth mentioning that I can't change the HTML code set up.

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I hope I've made myself clear enough.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've finally figured it out. Just implemented James Montagne's solution for the problem. I moved the div of the first image inside the "slide" div. Provided the divs containing the images were already absolute positioned, all I had to do was create a parent div which embodies both images and set a position relative to it. Worked 100% for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**html:**

```
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="top"></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#bottom{ 
    background: url(*bottom-image-url*); 
    position: relative; 
    width: *??*; 
    height: *??*;}
#top{ 
    background: url(*top-image-url*); 
    position: absolute; 
    width: *??*; 
    height: *??*; 
    left: *??*; 
    right: *??*;}
```