# Can I make a movable object on a map with php?

Tags: php

This is probably a real stupid question. I apologize before hand.

If I have a map, say 900px by 900px. And if I have a dot representing myself on the map as my current location and I also have arrows pointing N,E,S,W where someone can click to go one degree in that direction can I make it so the dot goes one degree on the map in direction clicked?

Basically a background image with another small image that overlays, that moves based on coordinates. The page would refresh each time a user click on N,E,S or W.

I have seen this done, but I wanna do it in PHP. Possible?

I figured I could do it without an image at all using if statements.

and having two more values in my SQL database.

```
    $North = 1;
    $East = 1;
    $South = -1;
    $West = -1;

$user['uLocation1'] $user['uLocation2']
```

If you go north the database would update with

```
 uLocation1=ulocation1+$North
```

Your new location would be 1,0

I hope I didn't confuse anyone by what I wrote. Which I probably did.

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Its possible. But the web page will refresh each time the user clicks the direction. Php runs in the server. I think it will be better off to use javascript, then you can reload the map without refreshing the page.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely clear what part of this you need help on.  The PHP itself?  How to make the user interface that sends the clicked direction to PHP?  The database code?

Comment: Any idea on how to make an overlay image appear on another image based off coordinates?

Comment: Basically I want to know how to make an image appear on top of another image based off an if statement. If I am at coordinates 12,17 I want an image to appear in a certain spot. If I am at 13,17 I want it to appear at another spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the overlaying of the images, the accepted answer on here seems to have what you want:  [How to fix an image position relative to another image with different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474889/how-to-fix-an-image-position-relative-to-another-image-with-different-screen-siz)

It shows how to overlay two images with CSS and HTML.

Comment: I think this will do exactly what I'm looking for! Thank You!

Comment: Just for future reference, this was more of a CSS/HTML question than a PHP one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very new and trying to learn more and more as I go through trial and error.